# Nodejs DynamoDB DocumentClient FilterExpressions not applied to LastEvaluatedKey?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

When I perform a scan, I need to apply a filter to ensure only the type of records I need are returned. What I have noticed is that the LastEvaluatedKey returned does not take into account the FilterExpression applied.

My (scan) query:

```
{
    TableName: 'my_table',
    ExpressionAttributeNames: { '#pk': 'pk', '#sk': 'sk' },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: { ':pk': '$bugbeater_1#sector_', ':sk': '$test_entity#id_' },
    FilterExpression: '(begins_with(#pk, :pk) AND begins_with(#sk, :sk))'
}
```

The returned `LastEvaluatedKey`:

```
{
    pk: '$bugbeater_1#sector_0add31a7-500d-4849-b679-8eb5bd220889',
    sk: '$test#id_1ea21ed0-875d-4432-852f-07c316c12389'
}
```

I can understand this is likely a more fundamental implementation detail of DynamoDB, and not an issue with the DocumentClient. It does make the api more difficult to use when using a single table design.

My table has multiple entities in it, not all of which is "public" and/or for the same tenant. If I were to just use the LastEvaluatedKey value without additional processing, and return that value to the client for possible pagination, I would potentially leak keys to other tenants/entities.

In general, I'm hoping to ensure this doesn't occur; is there an official course of action for this scenario?

More specifically to my use case, I am able to identify whether or not the returned `LastEvaluatedKey` actually matches the expected pk/sk. That is to say in my case I can evaluate if a key matches my schema for a given entity.

Given the DynamoDB architecture, is it safe to assume that if that SK does not match my entity that it can be treated as a complete query with no further pagination? For example, I am looking for records where the SortKey beginsWith `$test_entity#id_` but the `LastEvaluatedKey` beginsWith `$test#id_`, can I assume `$test#id_` is returned because it sorts after `$test_entity#id_` therefore all records with `$test_entity#id_` have been exhausted?

I hope that all makes sense, if you need any more examples, detail, or clarification, let me know and I can provide anything needed to help get this resolved.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [DynamoDB docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Scan.html), you can use a `FilterExpression` with scans.  What is giving you the impression that this is not the case?

You implied that you are returning the `LastEvaluatedKey` to the server for follow up pagination requests, but did not show the code.  Are you making sure to specify the last evaluated key from the first request as the `ExclusiveStartKey` of the next scan request?

It sounds like you have the right mental model for pagination of scans in DynamoDB, but just need to work out the kinks in your implementation.

EDIT:

Updating as a result of clarifying comments.  It sounds like you are trying to determine when to stop paginating based on the value of the `LastEvaluatedKey`.  Doing so would infer that scan operations happen in a particular sort order.  I can't find any evidence in the docs to support that claim.

The scan operation has a 1 MB limit *before* filter expression is applied.  The `LastEvaluatedKey` merely identifies how far along the operation got before it hit the 1 MB limit. How would DDB know after the first request that you *don't* have more attributes that match the filter condition?

For example, what if you had the following item in your table:

```
{
  pk:`$bugbeater_1#sector_A`
  sk: `$test_entity#id_A`
}
```

Which page of the scan results would this result appear? Can you tell if it will be before or after the `LastEvaluatedKey` you outlined in your original question?

I would suggest following the advice of the DynamoDB docs: "The absence of LastEvaluatedKey is the only way to know that you have reached the end of the result set".

Since you have access to the data set, what do you find if you keep paginating?  Do you find results that match your FilterCondition?

Comment: > "According to the DynamoDB docs, you can use a FilterExpression with scans. What is giving you the impression that this is not the case?"  
No it does, I am using it in above params I pasted. The issue is that the `LastEvaluatedKey` that comes back has the PK and SK of a record that does _NOT_ adhere to that FilterExpression. I'll paste my code in the reply after this one but those snippets I put in my question are the actual params I gave to the docClient and the actual `LastEvaluatedKey` I received.

Comment: In lieu of a code snippet for now I'll bring more attention to what I pasted above. In short, The filter I have says `begins_with(#sk, :sk)` with `':sk': '$test_entity#id_'`. However the sk I got back on the `LastEvaluatedKey` starts with `$test#id_`, which doesnt match the `begins_with` as it's applied in the params. My question actually assumes this is expected behavior that cant change (maybe I'm wrong), and is actually about assumptions that could be made about that the remaining pages in this scenario. Namely if this scenario occurs is it safe to assume there are no further records?